# useNavigate() error - Object(...) is not a function (React router 6.12)

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I get the error: `Object(...) is not a function` when I execute `useNavigate()`. I am using React Router v6.12.1. This is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment} from 'react';
import {
  Link,
  useNavigate
} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Overview = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  console.log(navigate);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => navigate('orders')}>
        Go to orders
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Below is the full stack trace:

```
Object(...) is not a function
 Overview @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/my_plugin/1.0.0/my_plugin.chunk.0.js:12459
 <unknown> @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:166030
 <unknown> @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:166030
 EuiPageSection @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:129866
 <unknown> @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:166030
 EuiPageBody @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:128929
 <unknown> @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:166030
 EuiPage @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:128783
 ErrorBoundaryClass @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/my_plugin/1.0.0/my_plugin.chunk.0.js:8937
 ConnectFunction @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/my_plugin/1.0.0/my_plugin.chunk.0.js:6572
 Route @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:360863
 Route @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/my_plugin/1.0.0/my_plugin.chunk.0.js:1270
 Router @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:360492
 BrowserRouter @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm/kbn-ui-shared-deps-npm.dll.js:360097
 Provider @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/my_plugin/1.0.0/my_plugin.chunk.0.js:6277
 ReduxProvider @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/my_plugin/1.0.0/my_plugin.chunk.0.js:14466
 Provider @ http://10.40.0.14:5600/ieu/9007199254740991/bundles/plugin/kibanaReact/1.0.0/kibanaReact.plugin.js:1794
```

I am creating a custom plugin using React in Kibana (Elasticsearch-Kibana)

Comment: We'll likely need to see more code and details to have enough context. Can you [edit] to include the complete error message, any accompanying error stacktrace, and a more complete [mcve]?