# useSearchParams() error - Object(...) is not a function (React router 6.12)

Tags: react-router

I get the error: Object(...) is not a function when I execute useNavigate(). I am using React Router v6.12.1

I had a similar issue with useNavigate()
[useNavigate() error - Object(...) is not a function (React router 6.12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503969/usenavigate-error-object-is-not-a-function-react-router-6-12)

There is no complicated code involved. Just did the following in my code, to understand the working on SearchParams.

`const [searchParams, setsearchParams] = useSearchParams(); console.log(searchParams);`

**Dependencies**
`"dependencies": { "axios": "^1.3.4", "file-saver": "^2.0.5", "node-localstorage": "^2.2.1", "react-full-screen": "^1.1.1", "react-redux": "^8.0.5", "react-router": "^6.12.1", "react-router-dom": "^6.12.1" },`

Am I missing anything?

Comment: This post *basically* seems to be a duplicate of your previous post, which still has an open request for you to edit and include a [mcve]. That said, RRDv6.12.* was a problematic release, so I suggest rolling back to RRDv6.11.* or trying a RRDv6.13.* release to see if the issues were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try this import from react-router-dom

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function useLogoutTimer() {
  const userIsInactive = useFakeInactiveUser();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userIsInactive) {
      fake.logout();
      navigate("/session-timed-out");
    }
  }, [userIsInactive]);
}
```

I am attaching the link for reference https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: I have used this also. Same error.
Please refer to this stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503969/usenavigate-error-object-is-not-a-function-react-router-6-12

Comment: can you show more code or share the entier code

Comment: `import React, { Fragment} from 'react';

import {
  Link,
  useParams
} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Overview = () => {
  const [searchParams, setsearchParams] = useSearchParams(); 
  console.log(searchParams);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div> Hello </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};`

Comment: if you are importing use params then it should be like let { userId } = useParams();The useParams Hook returns an object of key/value pairs from the current URL's dynamic parameters.

As long as the params are matched to the <Route path>, the Hook will be able to access these values.

Comment: Problem is not with use Params, its with **useNavigate** and **useSearchParams**.
  
I believe the following is the first statement to be used after importing them:
const [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();

And the error, **Object(...) is not a function** is coming because of the function calls, **useNavigate()** and **useSearchParams()**.

I donot understand y this error is coming up. Becoz everything works well with useParams(), but not the above 2.

Comment: try adding that console in useffect like this useEffect(() => { console.log(searchParams); }, [searchParams]); and remove the console which is outside

Comment: The problem is not with the console.log() statement.

Its with this: **const [searchParams, setsearchParams] = useSearchParams();**. This function call, **useSearchParams()** in the above piece of code is causing the error.

Comment: could you please share the whole code

Comment: import React, { Fragment} from 'react';
import {   Link,   useParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'; 

export const Overview = () => {   
    // Error caused by this line
    const [searchParams, setsearchParams] = useSearchParams(); 
    console.log(searchParams); 
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div> Hello </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

Comment: try downgrading dom to other version like Downgrade to 6.11.2, for me its working